# Push Notification shows Alert containing JSON with cordova-plugin-fcm, cordova, angular, and firebase with App in Foreground

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, angular6, cordova-plugin-fcm

[image: image of notification]
I have a Cordova/Angular app using firebase for push notifications via the cordova-plugin-fcm plugin. The notifications are showing in the bar properly when the app is closed/in the background, but when the app is opened via a tap on bar notification (or already open) the notification itself is simply an alert box that contains the JSON alert object, instead of a formatted notification.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "FCMPlugin";
String message = "";
String title = "";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    Log.d(TAG, "==> MyFirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived");
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        message = getDataWithKey(remoteMessage.getData(), "message");
        title = getDataWithKey(remoteMessage.getData(), "title");
    }

    if( remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "\tNotification Title: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        Log.d(TAG, "\tNotification Message: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    };

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("wasTapped", false);
    for (String key : remoteMessage.getData().keySet()) {
            Object value = remoteMessage.getData().get(key);
            Log.d(TAG, "\tKey: " + key + " Value: " + value);
            data.put(key, value);
    };

    Log.d(TAG, "\tNotification Data: " + data.toString());
    FCMPlugin.sendPushPayload( data );
    sendNotification(title, message, data);
}
// [END receive_message]

private String getDataWithKey(Map<String, String> params, String fieldKey) {
    String data = "";
    try {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet()) {
            String key = param.getKey();
            String value = param.getValue();
            if(key.contentEquals(fieldKey)){
                if(!value.isEmpty()) {
                    data = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, "  getDataWithKey -- " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return data;
}

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody, Map<String, Object> data) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FCMPluginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    for (String key : data.keySet()) {
        intent.putExtra(key, data.get(key).toString());
    }
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

}

According to everything, I can find I have implemented the plugin properly, but my notifications are ugly AF as an Alert box full of JSON is not human readable.

here is the JSON object being sent through a REST API:

```
{  
   "to":"/topics/all",
   "priority":"high",
   "notification":{  
   "title":"App in Foreground Test",
   "body":"Test App in Foreground",
   "sound":"default",
   "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
   "icon":"fcm_push_icon"
},
 "data":{  
   "title":"App in Foreground Test",
   "message":"Test with app in Foreground",
   "param1":"value1",
   "param2":"value2"
 }
  }
```

Sending both notification & data payload so I get notifications while app is in background and foreground.

```
    public static void sendPushPayload(Map<String, Object> payload) {
    Log.d(TAG, "==> FCMPlugin sendPushPayload");
    Log.d(TAG, "\tnotificationCallBackReady: " + notificationCallBackReady);
    Log.d(TAG, "\tgWebView: " + gWebView);
    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        for (String key : payload.keySet()) {
            jo.put(key, payload.get(key));
            Log.d(TAG, "\tpayload: " + key + " => " + payload.get(key));
        }
        String callBack = "javascript:" + notificationCallBack + "(" + jo.toString() + ")";
        if(notificationCallBackReady && gWebView != null){
            Log.d(TAG, "\tSent PUSH to view: " + callBack);
            gWebView.sendJavascript(callBack);
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "\tView not ready. SAVED NOTIFICATION: " + callBack);
            lastPush = payload;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "\tERROR sendPushToView. SAVED NOTIFICATION: " + e.getMessage());
        lastPush = payload;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon:: Certainly this can not be the code you are using, because it shouldn't even compile. Nowhere are the variables  "message"  or "title"  declared. You have also changed `getDataWithKey()` so that it returns a `Map` which contradicts the method return type.

Comment: sorry, wrong code, I had modified some of it to try to pass the object (data) to the sendNotification method that is requesting

`private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody, Map<String, Object> data) {...`

Comment: @Barns for clarification, I would like the alert to have the title (Test with App in Foreground) instead of ALERT, and the message, of course, should be the "body" section of text instead of JSON it currently has...(I removed the other 2 params as they were unneeded.

Comment: @Barns:: added code to original post for sendPushPayload

Comment: I should have asked much earlier, but are you testing on a real device or emulator? What API level is your test device? And the image at the top of your question. Is that the "notification"  you are referring to that is "ugly json"?

Comment: Real Device, Yes, that image is a screen grab from the device of the actual alert being displayed. API level unkown...Device info: android (Google Pixel XL) running Android OS 9 Pie

Comment: Jon :: Have a look at my edited Answer for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the "ugly"  JSON in the notification because you are adding the body of the message directly as content of the Notification.

```
.setContentText(messageBody)
```

Extract the relevant information from the `messageBody` and add that information to `.setContentText()`.

To get the data from the `data` portion you can add something like this to your `onMessageReceived()` method:

```
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    message = getDataWithKey(remoteMessage.getData(), "message");
    title = getDataWithKey(remoteMessage.getData(), "title");
    param1 = getDataWithKey(remoteMessage.getData(), "param1");
    param2 = getDataWithKey(remoteMessage.getData(), "param2");
}
```

Then add this method:

```
private String getDataWithKey(Map<String, String> params, String fieldKey) {
    String data = "";
    try {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet()) {
            String key = param.getKey();
            String value = param.getValue();
            if(key.contentEquals(fieldKey)){
                if(!value.isEmpty()) {
                    data = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, "  getDataWithKey -- " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return data;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

The "ugly" notification is not coming from a  `Notification` it is coming from somewhere else in your code, because it is the exact same data that is add in this code:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("wasTapped", false); 
...
```

Which I see you are using in at least two locations:

```
FCMPlugin.sendPushPayload( data );
```

and

```
for (String key : data.keySet()) {
    intent.putExtra(key, data.get(key).toString());
}
```

**Also consider:** 
Newer Android OS versions require a `NotificationChannel` to work properly. Example code (you will need to change some parts of this to fit your needs):

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody, Map<String, Object> data) {
    try{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BusinessDetailActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        for (String key : data.keySet()) {
            intent.putExtra(key, data.get(key).toString());
        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                                                                0,
                                                                intent,
                                                                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); // PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String idNotification = createNotificationChannel();
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, idNotification)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_PROMO)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(SMALL_ICON);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            //TODO: You will need to define your own ID_NOTIFICATION!!
            notificationBuilder.setChannelId(ID_NOTIFICATION);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

        //TODO: I use a random number generator, but you do what fits your needs
        int idNot = CodeGenerator.getRandomNumber(10, 10000);
        assert (notificationManager != null);
        notificationManager.notify(idNot, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, "  sendNotification --- " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}



private String createNotificationChannel() {
    //TODO: You will need to define your own ID_NOTIFICATION!!
    String id = ID_NOTIFICATION;
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String name = "Special Notification";
            String desc = "Notification showing special information.";
            int prio = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, prio);
            channel.setShowBadge(true);
            channel.setDescription(desc);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.enableVibration(true);

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            assert (manager != null);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
    return id;
}
```

Comment: trying that now, will set as accepted answer should testing pass

Comment: @JonSmith :: Please be aware that the Firebase Cloud Message that contains a `Data` and a `Notification` section are handled differently by app then a message with only a `Data` section. Unfortunately, iOS does not handle message the same way Android does. For this reason I send different types of message so each OS. See the docs to see how :: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will have to implement iOS as soon as I have the android side working as it is a cross-platform app in development. I will keep your info in mind. Thanks for the help. I have a restrictive environment, so the build process is long and I am still testing your fix. I will accept as soon as I verify the fix is working, thanks again!

Comment: @JonSmith :: As I said in my answer-- The code that starts with `if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {` must go inside your `onMessageReceived()` method. According to the error you must have put it outside of the method.

Comment: API is Android-27

Comment: @JonSmith :: That would be Oreo which requires `NotificationChannel` or else the `Notification` will not appear on the device.  The "Alert" you are seeing is being generated somewhere else, because it contains this information: `Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("wasTapped", false); 
...`